# BIRT: PDF - Generation Time

Tags: reporting, report, birt

I'have a report, where the html generation for a preview takes about 39 seconds. When i try to preview the report in pdf, it's not done in 4 Minutes. Is that normal? My other reports have about 50% time - diference at maximum. 
If its not normal, how can i speed up the report generation in pdf?

Thanks!
(BIRT 2.1.3, RCP Designer )

Answer (score 1):

I would say 6x increase in generation time for PDF over HTML is not to be expected.

Most of my reports take no more than twice as long to export to PDF than they do to HTML. XLS export is in between HTML and PDF.

I was able to gain some optimisation on execution time by splitting up some data sets, and combining others. Some experimentation may provide you with some good results.

However a key thing to note was that my optimisation was spread across all export types, not just limited to PDF.

That isn't really much help, but it gives you something to try.